# Hibernate @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) with different schemata causes error (HHH000099)

Tags: java, hibernate

After upgrading from Hibernate 4.2 to 5.5.5 my inheritance isn't working anymore. Starting my application the following error is thrown:

> ERROR AssertionFailure:33 - HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Table `BASE.ANIMAL` not found

here my classes:

`cat.java`

```
package ext;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy(lazy=false)
@Table(name="CAT", schema="EXT")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ANIMALid", referencedColumnName="id")
public class CAT extends base.ANIMAL implements Serializable {
    public CAT() {
    }

    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }

}
```

`animal.java`

```
package base;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Proxy(lazy=false)
@Table(name="ANIMAL", schema="BASE")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue("ANIMAL")
public class ANIMAL implements Serializable {
    public ANIMAL() {
    }

    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, unique=true, length=10)  
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(generator="BASE_ANIMAL_ID_GENERATOR")   
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="BASE_ANIMAL_ID_GENERATOR", strategy="native", parameters={ @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name="schema", value="BASE") })   
    private int id;

    private void setId(int value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getORMID() {
        return getId();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(getId());
    }

}
```

testclass

```
package ormsamples;

import org.orm.*;
public class CreateJoinedinheritanceData {
    public void createTestData() throws PersistentException {
        PersistentTransaction t = ext.JoinedinheritancePersistentManager.instance().getSession().beginTransaction();
        try {
            base.ANIMAL bASEANIMAL = base.ANIMALDAO.createANIMAL();
            // Initialize the properties of the persistent object here
            base.ANIMALDAO.save(bASEANIMAL);
            ext.CAT eXTCAT = ext.CATDAO.createCAT();
            // Initialize the properties of the persistent object here
            ext.CATDAO.save(eXTCAT);
            t.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            t.rollback();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            CreateJoinedinheritanceData createJoinedinheritanceData = new CreateJoinedinheritanceData();
            try {
                createJoinedinheritanceData.createTestData();
            }
            finally {
                ext.JoinedinheritancePersistentManager.instance().disposePersistentManager();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

have i missed a migration step or is there a bug in the latest hibernate 5 release?

looking forward for your suggestions!

Comment: @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) is required only in parent class and not in child class, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Correct, but the error remains the same 

Comment: https://github.com/shubhamchopra3/Hibernate-demo/tree/master/hibernate-10 you can refer my git repo, here I have created JoinedStrategy inheritance with hibernate 5.2

Comment: thanks for the link, but your example is without schemata and I think this is the problem in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research I ran into this hibernate bug [HHH-10490](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10490).

It was rejected with the answer to use `catalog` instead of `schema`. Unfortunately no further explanation was given, but if I change this line

```
@Table(name="ANIMAL", schema="BASE")
```

to

```
@Table(name="ANIMAL", catalog="BASE")
```

everything works fine again.

Similarly to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084932/unable-to-build-hibernate-sessionfactory-when-using-joined-inheritance#44895039), also described by bug author [here](https://rogersuen.blogspot.com/2016/).